# How to return cfdocument pdf file and server to the user in the browser?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfdocument, cffunction

I have function that will generate cfdocument pdf file. Then I would like to return the document and server to the browser. Here is example of the function that generates the pdf file.

```
<cftry>
    <cfdocument format="PDF" filename="file.pdf" overwrite="Yes">
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>Test</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </cfdocument>

    <cfset local.fnResults = {file: //Here I'm not sure what I should return}>         

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfset local.fnResults = {status : 400, message : "Error! Something went wrong."}>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfreturn fnResults>
```

Function above should genrate the file and return PDF in `fnResults` structure. Then on `serve.cfm` I have this logic:

```
<cfset local.Results = genertePDF()>

<cfif structKeyExists(local.Results, "FILEPATH")>
        <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=#local.Results["FILENAME"]#"/>

        <!---Add the file content to the output stream:--->
        <cfcontent file="#local.Results["FILEPATH"]#" type="application/octet-stream" reset="true"/>

        <!---Exit immediately after adding the file content to avoid corrupting it:--->
        <cfabort/>
    <cfif>
```

You can ignore the structure of RESULTS since I haven't modified everything. My only problem here is to figure out how to return `cfdocument` content? If anyone knows how to get this to work please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Are you saving all of these files or are they just transient? How many files do you expect to generate?

Comment: @Shawn This feature generates PDF file once user clicks on the button. This page is front end content that should be converted to PDF. I have tried using `jspdf` but a lot of things are not working or hard to adjust. This approach seems like a good option so far. I can have multiple users on the same page at the same time using this feature. I'm not sure if this approach is good way to handle generating PDF documents?

Comment: Just take out the filename and it will stream the content straight back to the browser.

Comment: @Shawn If I take out file name file didn't show up.

Comment: It should. Unless maybe it's being used differently than we're thinking? Could you please post a small example showing how the code is invoked?

Comment: If you read my question you will find the example on how I call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=#local.Results["FILENAME"]#"/>
```

To:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="inline;filename=#local.Results["FILENAME"]#"/>
```

[Reference](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcontent.html)